# Plone - text color and background color not working in TinyMCE editor

Tags: plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3 and the default TinyMCE wysisyg editor, and have problem with the text color and background color.   Text Color and Background Color just do not work.   When we are editing the page, Text Color and Background Color work as we can see the text and background in the colors we had selected. But as soon as we save the page, the colors disappeared, i.e. the text is back to the default black color again and the background the default white color.   That is, the text and background colors do not work in the View mode of the page.

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Comment: Have you checked in the HTML filter control panel that the attributes are not filtered out on saving?

Comment: Thank you Ulrich.  Fixed the problem by adding permitted CSS style properties: color and background-color in HTML Filtering settings.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for above info.  I've added more details/specificity for newcomers to plone... [Also updating to Plone 4.3.2.]

1. Go to Site Setup and click on "HTML Filtering"
2. Choose the sub-tab, "Styles", click on button, "add permitted styles" [in Plone 4.3.2 it's called, "Add Permitted properties"]
3. Since the refresh takes you back a screen, re-click back on the "Styles" sub-tab.
4. In the new blank line, type in: color
5. Repeat steps 2 - 4 above, but this time type: background-color
6. Click on save.

If you haven't already placed the color picker tools into the toolbar:
 7. Click on the TinyMCE Visual Editor control panel, and click on the "toolbar" sub-tab.
 8. Put checks next to: Forecolor and Backcolor, and save.

Comment: Thanks for documentating the details. You might also accept your answer.